# Typo3/Typoscript: get data from (page) media ressources

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using Typo3 6.2.15 and want to upload some files at page->ressources->media like jpegs, mp4s, pngs...

To switch the output of the different filetypes, I tried it with the following script without success:

```
  HEADER = CASE
  HEADER {
      key.data = levelmedia: -1, slide
      key.listNum = 0
      key.split {
          token = .
          returnKey = 1
      }
      jpg = TEXT
      jpg.value = test
  }
```

Has anybody an idea whats the problem?

Comment: has nobody a idea? :(

Comment: I have no idea of what you try to archive. Please update your question on tell what you really want to do and how the generated HTML should loke like.

Comment: I want to upload different types of files at page->ressources->media, like jpg and mp4. Then at my typoscript, I want to switch on the filetype. Output jpg should be like <img src="..., mp4 should be <video .....